# genymotion device freezes when using new devices

Tags: android, windows, genymotion

When I run Genymotion and want to start a relatively new device it freezes with a strange screen but with older devices like android 5 or 7 I don't have such problem.
I updated Genymotion version, edited my devices to lower memory size and processor core number but it made no change. It doesn't stuck in booting like so many others that have problem and its status is "On".
I use:
-windows 10, Genymotion V3.1.1.
-GPU nvidia geforce GT550M 2GB
-CPU intel core i5
-display driver is updated
This is what I see in this device:
[image: Genymotion device screen]

These files are genymotion log: [Download Link](https://gofile.io/d/bj3IIM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically an issue with the GPU and/or display driver. Does your GPU meet Genymotion requirements? Is your display driver up to date?
Also, if you use a laptop with dual GPUs, make sure to read this article: https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002732678-Virtual-device-display-is-black-Genymotion-Desktop-

UPDATE:
I can see the following in the logs: `Running on a Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 from Intel` It means that Genymotion is not using your discrete NVidia GPU but your low-end Intel iGP which is too low to support Android 8 and above rendering. You need to force Genymotion player (player.exe) to use your NVidia GPU instead.
See https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Faq/How-to-force-Optimus-or-Switchable-discrete-GPUs/97

Comment: Thanks!  
I checked these items But apparently non of them is the problem.

Comment: I can see the following in the logs:

`Running on a Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 from Intel`

It means that Genymotion is not using your discrete NVidia GPU but your low-end Intel iGP which is too low to support Android 8 and above rendering.

You need to force Genymotion player (player.exe) to use your NVidia GPU instead.

Comment: See https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Faq/How-to-force-Optimus-or-Switchable-discrete-GPUs/97

Comment: Thank you so much! it solved my problem. I add this to your first answer.